# JS Garbage Collection: Are declared functions (which are not called) garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

I am new to memory management in JS, so please pardon if this is a dumb question.

Suppose I have a component with three functions defined and a switch case statement which calls only one function depending on the case matched. Will the other two functions occupy the memory or they are garbage collected once the switch statement is executed?

```
function funcA() {};
function funcB() {};
function funcC() {};

switch(type) {
    case 'funcA':
        funcA();
        break;
    case 'funcB':
        funcB();
        break;
    case 'funcC':
        funcC();
        break;
}
```

Comment: how can something be garbage collected that isnt even executed?

Comment: @bill.gates I thought the function declaration would occupy some space in the memory even if it wasn't called.

Comment: You can call pretty much any named function from the console, after all the page code has executed.  That wouldn't work if the function had been garbage collected.

Comment: @James makes sense. I know this is a bad use case of having functions defined this way rather than using separate modules 

... but just out of curiosity, would you suggest moving the function declarations inside the `case` statement so that the only functions which get declared are the ones that match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If defined inside a function scope and not at the top-level of the document, any local variables referenced only inside that scope (including function definitions) will be garbage collected at some point after the function finishes executing.

You can verify this using [FinalizationRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/FinalizationRegistry) like so:

```js
function memoryExperiment(type) {
    function funcA() {};
    function funcB() {};
    function funcC() {};
    
    const registry = new FinalizationRegistry((heldValue) => {
        console.log(`Garbage collected ${heldValue}`)
    });
    registry.register(funcA, "funcA")
    registry.register(funcB, "funcB")
    registry.register(funcC, "funcC")

    switch(type) {
        case 'funcA':
            funcA();
            break;
        case 'funcB':
            funcB();
            break;
        case 'funcC':
            funcC();
            break;
    }

    return registry
}

const registry = memoryExperiment('funcA')
```

A message is logged for all three functions indicating they were garbage collected.

It is difficult to predict exactly when they will be collected as the garbage collection algorithm makes decisions based on various factors, but in my testing on an otherwise blank html file in Chrome it's usually after a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, @Toggle. The functions are part of a module but defined outside of the switch case, so I guess they will be collected irrespective of being called.

Comment: JS bundlers have traditionally compiled source modules to function scopes; I'm not sure how modern native ESM modules would behave, but I imagine it's similar, yep.